# change the default display message of QKeySequenceEdit?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

[image]

when adding a QKeySequenceEdit, theres this default display message "Press shortcut".
is there any way to change or delete it?
i tried to look for here (https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qkeysequenceedit-members.html) but it doesnt seem to provide any options for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem and found a way to deal with it after reading the answer from @SebDieBln. I am not a programmer, so this is probably not the most elegant solution but it worked for my needs, at least.

I have a separate settings class where I handle changing hotkeys, so I applied Sebs suggestion where I added the `QKeySequenceEdit`:

```
self.hotkey_edit = QKeySequenceEdit(self)
line_edit = self.hotkey_edit.findChild(QLineEdit, "qt_keysequenceedit_lineedit")
    if line_edit:
        line_edit.setPlaceholderText("Enter custom Placeholdertext here")
```

I was already using an `eventFilter` to intercept other events, so I installed it on the settings class upon creation in my main window class:

```
self.settings_dialog.installEventFilter(self)
```

and made it listen for changes on the QKeySequenceEdit, and if the text is cleared, reset the placeholder text:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    if hasattr(self, 'settings_dialog') and self.settings_dialog:
        if obj == self.settings_dialog.hotkey_edit and event.type() == QEvent.Type.KeyRelease:
            line_edit = self.settings_dialog.hotkey_edit.findChild(QLineEdit, "qt_keysequenceedit_lineedit")
            if line_edit and not line_edit.text():
                line_edit.setPlaceholderText("Enter custom Placeholdertext here")

    return super().eventFilter(obj, event)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qkeysequenceedit.cpp#n73) it looks like this value is hard coded.

However since the displayed `QLineEdit` is a child of the `QKeySequenceEdit` object you might be able to find it using [QKeySequenceEdit::children()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#children) (its object name is "qt_keysequenceedit_lineedit", [see source](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qkeysequenceedit.cpp#n21)). Once you have it you can then modify the displayed text by calling its [`QLineEdit::setPlaceholderText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop).

Note that you probably need to do that not just after the creation of the `QKeySequenceEdit` because the placeholder text is set at multiple occasions, i.e. after the user has input a key sequence.

Comment: hello sir, i tried what you said and its working quite well except they are set at multiple occasions like you said. so i was wondering if theres anyway to change the source code. i tried to find it in C:\Users\aos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\PySide6 but it doesnt seem to have the source. do you have any idea?

Comment: @kerz PySide is just a Python binding. The Qt library is written in C++, as clearly visible in the source code linked above.

Comment: @musicamante yes but im not familiar with all this. i mean i can edit the c++ file easily but how would i be able to put it back to pyside6? i found the the guide about building from source on their official website but the links provided there doesnt seem to work anymore.
(https://pypi.org/project/PySide6/)

Comment: @kerz Yes, you'd need to rebuild the whole Qt library, and then PySide along with that, but that wouldn't make a lot of sense for two reasons: 1. it would only work on your computer, unless you deploy your program along with your custom Qt build; 2. you just need a basic implementation that can be easily done from Python using what suggested above. Patching Qt and rebuilding it (and PySide along with it) for this simple reason would be like killing a mosquito with a bazooka. Just create a subclass of QKeySequenceEdit and implement support for changing the placeholder text.